# replacing vales in one table with values from another table using multiple criteria

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, inner-join

I have two tables, one called accajd, which a screenshot of is shown below, which has the old and new values in it. and one called jobcost with about 15 fields, 3 of which need to be updated with the data from the accadj table (accno, jno, and saccno). What i need to do is everywhere in job cost that the data from the accno, jno, and saccno fields matches the accnoold, jnoold, and saccnoold from accadj, i need to replace the data in jobcost with the values from accnonew, jnonew, and saccnonew from accadj.

[image: accadj database sample]

```
update jobcost 
set accno =(SELECT accadj.[accnonew] FROM accadj 
   WHERE accadj.id = jobcost.[jno] 
  AND accadj.[saccnoold] = jobcost.[saccno]),
jno =(SELECT accadj.[accnonew] FROM accadj 
   WHERE accadj.id = jobcost.[jno] 
  AND accadj.[saccnoold] = jobcost.[saccno]),
saccno =(SELECT accadj.[accnonew] FROM accadj 
   WHERE accadj.id = jobcost.[jno] 
  AND accadj.[saccnoold] = jobcost.[saccno])
```

this is all I could come up with as far as writing a query goes for this task, and its nowhere close to working. the jobcost table has about 15,000 entries, so this code would only end up replacing about 100 of them

Comment: As written your code won't update anything because you can't have multiple where clauses and the commas in them I don't quite understand.

Comment: the code is a poor attempt to make it happen, ive seen on other pages the use of an inner join but i dont know how to use those. basically if all 3 columns match, then replace all 3 columns with the new values. and i have absolutely no idea how to make this happen but i get scolded on here when i dont put some kind of attempted code

Comment: UPDATE jobcost 
SET accno =(SELECT accadj.[accnonew]
  FROM accadj
  WHERE accadj.[jnoold]=jobcost .[jno]  AND accadj.[saccnoold] = jobcost.[saccno]);

Comment: I dont have an id column. no column has all unique info, that's why they have to be matched on multiple fields

Comment: try to implement the above code in your code may be it works

Comment: it gave me "Invalid column name 'id'"

Comment: i updated the code too show what the updated code looked like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Below code it will work for sure  ,

```html
Update jc
set jc.accno = ac.accnonew,jc.jno =ac.accnonew,jc.saccno =ac.saccnonew
from jobcost jc join accadj ac with(nolock)
on jc.accno  = ac.accnoold
and jc.jno  = ac.jnoold
and jc.saccno =ac.saccnoold
```

Thanks

Comment: im guessing i should replace all the jc with jobcost and all the ac with accadj?

Comment: why ? it will work with alias .is any issue with Alias..?

Comment: Why would you use nolock here? Do you know what that hint brings to the table? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I considered it as static table .... which is my wrong .. thanks for opening my eyes ... info may update in between ...what will be the better option readpast,readcommited     tablock or no hint?  if we use readcommited ,readpast than there is possiblity that all rows not update in single run .it not  deterministic .. on other hand if we use tablock or no hint than it will may strive for lock ..

Comment: I didnt know what no lock did, but yes, the table changes between every time I need to run this program